# Wildcard in the middle of an expression?

Tags: regex, r

I try to load files in different categories according to theis file name. Till now I always used

```
list<-dir(pattern=".gle$")
```

to get all gle-files. Now I want to load the populations bg, campo & pca seperately and I am searching for a wildcard which can be used in the middle of filenames, which are e.g.

```
0KK_bg_SunAdj.gle
0LC_campo_SunAdj.gle
0KR_pca_SunAdj_corr.gle
```

I thought of something like

```
list<-dir(pattern=glob2rx("*something*bg*something*.gle$"))
```

but I tried all the examples in the `?glob2rx` help file and did not succeed.
I'm sure it is possible (I mean; it's R...) but i cannot figure it out...

Thanks!

Comment: probably you don't need the `$` at the end of the argument to `glob2rx`

Comment: @kohske: ok! But what shall I use in the middle (between bg and .gle)?

Comment: `pattern = "bg"`, `pattern = campo"` and `pattern = "pca"` don't cut it?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Like BenBarnes mentiones in his answer; with your patterns I get non-gle files in my lists aswell...

Comment: I was not aware other files are also present (but looking back, it does make sense now), sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
list1<-dir(pattern="[[:print:]]*_bg_[[:print:]]*.gle")
list2<-dir(pattern="[[:print:]]*_campo_[[:print:]]*.gle")
list3<-dir(pattern="[[:print:]]*_pca_[[:print:]]*.gle")
```

But these might pick up other files in the directory. If not, then @RomanLuštrik probably hit the nail on the head in the comment above. **EDIT**: Actually, @RomanLuštrik 's comment would pick up non-.gle files. So the above code would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the other options in the `glob2rx` function for trimming the head and tail. For example,

```
R> f = c("0KK_bg_SunAdj.gle", "0LC_campo_SunAdj.gle", "0KR_pca_SunAdj_corr.gle")
R> m = glob2rx("*campo*.gle", FALSE, FALSE)
R> grepl(m, f)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```